# make: *** No rule to make target hide_pic.h', needed by hideqr.o'. Stop

Tags: c++

When I write Makefile below, It went run,how to solve?

```
hideqr.o : hide_pic.cpp hide_pic.h  
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} -c $< -I/home/wangxiaofei01/hideqr/hideqr/hideqr/include -o $@
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First, chechout if the file of hide_pic.h has the common dir path with Makefile, if not, then change `hideqr.o : hide_pic.cpp hide_pic.h`  to `hideqr.o : hide_pic.cpp`, then use -I option to specify `hide_pic.h` path; The example is below;

```
HDIEQR_ROOT:=$(shell cd ../../.. && pwd)
HIDEQR_INCLUDE = -I$(HDIEQR_ROOT)/hideqr/hideqr/include
$(warning $(HIDEQR_INCLUDE)) # -I/home/wangxiaofei01/hideqr/hideqr/hideqr/include
hideqr.o : hide_pic.cpp
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} -c $< $(HIDEQR_INCLUDE) -o $@
```